# PHP tokenize a tweet in words, punctuation, hashtag, mentions, emoticons

Tags: php, string, tokenize, tweets, preg-split

I would like to tokenize a tweet. As you probably know, tweets usually have informal forms, as follow:

```
This is a common Tweet #format where @mentions and.errors!!!!like this:-))))) might #appear❤ ❤☺❤#ThisIsAHashtag!?!
```

You may also have emoji in UNICODE format (heart, smiles, etc).
I'm working on a preg_split to tokenize. The desidered ouput is:

```
This
is
a
common
Tweet
#format
where
@mentions
and
.
errors
!!!!
like
this
:-)))))
might
#appear
❤
❤
☺
❤
#ThisIsAHashtag
!?!
```

The current preg_split I've implemented so far is:

```
preg_split('/(?<=\s)|(?<=\w)(?=[.,:;!?(){}-])|(?<=[.,!()?\x{201C}])(?=[^ ])/u', $tweet);
```

Any help is appreciate.

Comment: how does/should this differ from `explode(' ',$tweet)` ? and why is the 5th token `tweet` but you want `Tweet` ?

Comment: @birdspider exploding by space doesn't work as there are tokens in his example tweet that are not separated by spaces.

Comment: Sorry, Tweet was mean to be uppercase in the original tweet. Exactly, the split by ' ' (spaces) can't be done...

Comment: Why ❤ ❤❤ is splitted into three lines?

Comment: @ST3 because you have "#appear❤ ❤❤#" - So the space is not tokenize. I want each emoji alone. The second series ❤❤# might be ☺☺❤❤ So each emoji shoul be tokenized.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this pattern with `preg_match_all`:

```
~[#@]?\w+|\pP+|\S~u
```

[online demo](http://regex101.com/r/zD1hI8/2)

Note: You can easily extend this pattern if you need to group another kind of characters. Example with currency:

```
~[#@]?\w+|\pP+|\p{Sc}+|\S~u
```

Comment: This is Amazing! Moreover, I was not aware about that regex101 web site. Thank you.. you made my day.

Comment: I have a doubt. How to have token like I'm, it's? I mean those whit the apostrophe between two words?

Comment: ~[#@]?\w+[']?\w*|\pP+|\p{Sc}+|\S~u  => I've done like this. thanks :)